# How to make Set using spring-data-aerospike

Tags: spring-boot, aerospike

Environment:

- spring-boot v2.0.4 RELEASE
- spring-data-aerospike v2.0.1.RELEASE
- java - 8

Here are my application code and properties.

```java
// application.properties
aerospike.hosts=xxx:3000
aerospike.namespace=test

// aerospike configuration class
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AerospikeConfiguration.AerospikeConfigurationProperties.class)
@EnableAerospikeRepositories(basePackageClassses = TestAeroRepository.class)
public class AerospikeConfiguration extends AbstractAerospikeDataConfiguration {
  private final AerospikeConfigurationProperties aerospikeConfigurationProperties;

  @Override
  protected Collection<Host> getHosts() {
      return Host.parseServiceHosts(aerospikeConfigurationProperties.getHosts());
  }

  @Override
  protected String nameSpace() {
    return aerospikeConfigurationProperties.getNamespace();
  }

  @Data
  @Validate
  @ConfigurationProperties("aerospike")
  public static class AerospikeConfigurationProperties {
     @NotEmpty
     String hsots;

     @NotEmpty
     String namespace;
  }
}

# Entity class
@Value
@Document
@Builder(toBuilder = true)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class testEntity() {
   @Id
   int id;

   @Field
   String name;

   @Field
   String timestamp;
}

@Repository
public interface TestAeroRepository extends AerospikeRepository<TestEntity, Integer> {
}

public interface TestAeroService {
  void save();
}

@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class TestAeroServiceImpl implements TestAeroService {
  private final TestAeroRepository testAeroRepository;

  @Override
  public void save(TestEntity entity) {
    testAeroRepository.save(entity);
  }
}
```

I checked Aerospike client connection has no problem.
But error is occurred when save() method is executed.

> org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils.defineClass(Ljava/lang/String;[BLjava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/security/ProtectionDomain;Ljava/lang/Class;)Ljava/lang/Class;

Have to make sets before execute the application? 
 I didn't make sets.
Any problem with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You’re using an old version of spring-data-aerospike (2.0.1.RELEASE was released on April 2019) is there any chance you can upgrade to the latest version? 2.4.2.RELEASE

You can see how to setup a simple spring data aerospike application here: https://medium.com/aerospike-developer-blog/simple-web-application-using-java-spring-boot-aerospike-database-and-docker-ad13795e0089

Please share the entire project’s code and the entire exception.

I would look into:

1. The configuration class (The Aerospike Beans creation).
2. The content of the testEntity class - are you using @Id annotation on the primary key field?
3. Extending the repository class with specifying the testEntity object (… extends AerospikeRepository<testEntity, Object> {) you can see an example in the link I added.

Comment: thanks for hep. I edited code. and that message above is the only main exception message.

Comment: You don't have to create Sets in order to write to Aerospike, the default is to write directly to the namespace, if you decide that you want to write to a specific set just specify "collection" field in the @Document annotation, for example: @Document(collection = "set-name"). Regarding your error, i'm not sure you can write the code above with the versions you specified, upgrading to spring-data-aerospike 2.4.2 is not an option? it will make your life easier since there is much more documentation for the latest versions. Can you also add the entire stack trace of your exception?

Answer (score 0):

The set is automatically created and takes the name of your object class, which is testEntity in your case. For example, based on your code, if you do not specify a collection in the `@Document` annotation a set named `"testEntity"` will automatically be created. I added the `@Document(collection = "testEntitys")` annotation and all I did was create two set. Once you insert your first record, run the `"SHOW SETS"` aql command and it will be there. So that's one way to do it.